# Reload the image from url after every 1 second in Android

Tags: android, image, url

I know how to load an image from url. However, I don't know how to reload it after 1 second. If the image changes, the image view also changes with the same url.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        // Retrieve your image from a URL here ...
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Comment: Is it ok if I re-download the image from url every 1 second? I meant that I have to repeat these works such as OpenConnection, DownloadImage... every 1 second, will it be good in performance?

Comment: Sure you can download an image every second, but you'll have to consider the connection speed (WIFI vs 4G), the size of the image you are downloading, limited battery life, etc. Perhaps you'd be better off just checking to see if the image has changed, instead of downloading it each time. This could be as simple as checking a file timestamp and making a comparison. If the timestamp has changed then download the latest version of the image. This would greatly reduce your dependence on the connection speed and download limits.

Comment: How to compare file timestamp? Can you explain more?

Comment: Keep a local copy of your image timestamp (possibly in a SQLite database). Pass the timestamp to a service hosted on your server (probably easiest just to pass the millisecond value). Compare the timestamp being passed in to a timestamp on the server (you may have to take into account timezones here). If the timestamps are different then return the new image, otherwise return null. On the Android side if the service returns an image then display it, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [timer and timertask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29) of 1 sec to reload the imageview from the url

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can use a background service or ContentObserver class to implement such feature. ContentObserver keeps watch on your content and notifies you when any change has occurred. Go through this link :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html